# In the single-shoot, double slit experiment, does the screen register one corresponding particle for each one fired or more than one each time?

Tags: double-slit-experiment

This info is crucial for my research. Are there any experimenters here who actually did the experiment and can confirm if this is the case?

Comment: It measures one each time. This is fundamental to quantum mechanics and the idea of a photon. Are you having doubts that such experiments have been done? The Photoelectric Effect is also relevant.

Comment: Why do you think the particles might multiply between source and target? Can you suggest an experiment to test that hypothesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photons are quantum mechanical entities, and in the famous double slit experiment, these photons are shot one at a time. Each time you shoot a photon, there will be one single dot on the screen.

> Any photon that gets past the slits will make at most one mark on the detector, but the detector probably is less than 100% efficient, and some photons may fail to leave a mark.

[In a double slit experiment, does each and every photon leave a dot on the screen in the bright area?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/506916/in-a-double-slit-experiment-does-each-and-every-photon-leave-a-dot-on-the-scree)

So the ultimate answer to your question is yes, one photon shot at a time will register one single dot on the screen (except if no dot, because of experimental error).